# How to define a subclass in java (basic inheritance)

Tags: java, inheritance

I have been reading up on inheritance in java, and I have a fairly simple problem that I couldn't find on the manual pages.

Take [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) example.

I want define a class first:

```
Bycicle bike = new Bicycle();
```

Later on I want to say that it is a mountain bike, so that it belongs to a certain subclass and set a property speficit to mountain bike (say numberOfGears).

Is that possible in this order? Or do I need to say it is a  mountainbike straight away?

Comment: What @Marco ment was MountainBike mbike = (MountainBike) bike;

Comment: How would that work exactly, so Mountainbike bike = new Mountainbike()? I would keep the info in Bike?

Comment: Maybe some of the basic tutorials from Oracle might help you even more to get started: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/.

Comment: Oh your link points to those tutorials.. uhm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know you will only use `Bycicle`'s methods, then declare and initialize the variable as `Bycicle`:

```
Bycicle bike = new Bicycle();
```

If you want to change the class implementation but still use only `Bycicle` methods, then declare the variable as `Bycicle` and initialize it as the specific class implementation, in this case, `MountainBike`:

```
Bycicle bike = new MountainBike();
```

If you know you will use specific methods of the class implementation, then you have two choices:

- Initialize as the class implementation and in the specific part you need to call a method from this class implementation, use downcasting:

  ```
  ((MountainBike)bike).mountainBikeMethod();
  ```

  I don't recommend this approach since if you change how you initialize the class then you should be careful when changing these downcastings as well, otherwise you will get `RuntimeException`, specifically `ClassCastException` for downcasting to a wrong class.
- Declare and initialize as the class implementation, then forget about using the super class type since that's not what you need:

  ```
  MountainBike bike = new MountainBike();
  ```

Comment: This is the way to go

Comment: Be careful with casting though, as its a common source for runtime exceptions

Comment: @MatiCicero note added when you were adding the comment.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to say it is a mountain bike you need to create a MountainBike instance, not just Bicycle. Then you can just downcast it. But this seems a bit unnatural so either refer to that bicycle as to the MountainBicycle in the first place or adapt it to be a mountain bicycle using adapter design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

An instanciated object from a class can't be changed to other class later.

Anyway a MounteinBike is still a bike. Then you can do:

```
Bycicle bike = new MountainBike();
```

or

```
MountainBike mountainBike = new MountainBike();
```

When it is possible is preffered to use the higher level of abstraction, In this case the first example.